# Directing the user to a child state when they are transitioning to its parent state using UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Consider the following:

```
.state('manager.staffList', {url:'^/staff?alpha', templateUrl: 'views/staff.list.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}, controller: 'staffListCtrl'})
.state('manager.staffDetail', {url:'^/staff/{id}' , templateUrl: 'views/staff.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}, controller: 'staffDetailsCtrl'})
  .state('manager.staffDetail.view', {url:'/view',  templateUrl: 'views/staff.details.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
    .state('manager.staffDetail.view.schedule', {url:'/schedule', templateUrl:'views/staff.view.schedule.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
    .state('manager.staffDetail.view.history', {url:'/history' , templateUrl:'views/staff.view.history.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
    .state('manager.staffDetail.view.log', {url:'/log', templateUrl:'views/staff.view.log.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
    .state('manager.staffDetail.view.files', {url:'/files', templateUrl:'views/staff.view.files.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
  .state('manager.staffDetail.edit', {url:'/edit',  templateUrl: 'views/staff.edit.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
```

If I go to `example.com/staff/1234/view`, how do I default to the `manager.staffDetail.view.schedule` child state?

Comment: FYI, I currently use the `redirectTo` method found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491079/redirect-a-state-to-default-substate-with-ui-router-in-angularjs

Comment: Please do NOT edit this to create more vertical code. The code is formatted specifically to visually show the child states in comparison to their parents.

Comment: @UdayHiwarale that is the same link already posted above

Comment: My bad. I did not see.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

1. First, add a property to the `'manager.staffDetail.view'` state of **`abstract:true`**. This isn't required, but you want to set this since you'd never go to this state directly, you'd always go to one of it's child states.
2. Then do **one** of the following:

- Give the `'manager.staffDetail.view.schedule'` state an **empty URL**. This will make it match the same URL as it's parent state URL, because it appends nothing to the parent URL.

  ```
   `.state('manager.staffDetail.view.schedule', {url:'', ...`
  ```
- Or if you want to keep the URL of the default child route unchanged, then set up a **redirect** in your `module.config`. This code here will redirect any location of `'/staff/{id}/view'` to the location of `'/staff/{id}/view/schedule'`:

  ```
   `$urlRouterProvider.when('/staff/{id}/view', '/staff/{id}/view/schedule');`
  ```

Comment: For the `$urlRouterProvider` redirect, I got an error when using a link with `ui-sref="manager.staffDetail.view"`, so I needed to remove `abstract: true` from the parent state declaration.

Comment: second option will not work for internal ui-sref links (it will not go to substate)

Answer (score 20):

For setting default child view , check this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ac2yUjEO0q0bzsRfjum6?p=preview) . On clicking `Route 1` load default state `route1.list`

```
// For any unmatched url, send to /route1
$stateProvider
  .state('route1', {
      url: "/route1",
      abstract:true ,
      templateUrl: "route1.html"
  })
  .state('route1.list', {
      url: '',
      templateUrl: "route1.list.html",
      controller: function($scope){
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }
  })
  .state('route1.desc', {
      url: "/desc",
      templateUrl: "route1.desc.html",
      controller: function($scope){
        $scope.items = [];
      }
  })
  .state('route2', {
    url: "/route2",
    templateUrl: "route2.html"
  })
  .state('route2.list', {
    url: "/list",
    templateUrl: "route2.list.html",
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
    }
  })
```

Comment: If `route1.desc` has no url, you could still reach it with `$state.go`, but `route1.list` would be loaded by default on `/route1` :) this is useful if you don't want to give direct access to the state via url

Comment: there is a big problem with this if we want to use the parent state in ui-sref

Comment: you have to use href="/abstractroute" to link to the parent

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why the `route1` state in this example needs a templateUrl? Or more generally, why would an `abstract:true` state need a template?

Comment: the Parent of the child should have the one with `abstract:true`

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue and found this solution to work:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/948#issuecomment-75342784

This is quoted from @christopherthielen on github

> "For now, don't declare your state abstract, and use this recipe:"

```
 app.run($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    });
  }

  $stateProvider.state('parent' , {
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: "parent.html",
      redirectTo: 'parent.child'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('parent.child' , {
      url: "/child",
      templateUrl: "child.html"
  });
```

**Here is breakdown of how the process works:**

1. User navigates to state “parent”
2. “$stateChangeStart” event gets fired
3. Listener for “$stateChangeStart” catches event and passes “toState” (which is “parent”) and “event" to the handler function
4. Handler function checks if “redirectTo” is set on “toState”.
5. If “redirectTo” IS NOT set, nothing happening and the user continues on to the “toState” state.
6. If “redirectTo" IS set, the event is canceled (event.preventDefault) and $state.go(toState.redirectTo) sends them to the state specified in “redirectTo” (which is “parent.child”).
7. The “$stateChangeStart” event gets fired again, but this time “toState” == “parent.child” and the “redirectTo” option is not set, so it continues to “toState”.

Comment: can anyone explain this. Will this not become infinite loop ?

Comment: Hi Kishore - I updated the answer to explain how it works. There will NOT be an infinite loop unless you explicitly specify the "parent" state in the "redirectTo" option.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I am using ui-router v0.3.1

Answer (score 7):

Quite late but I think you can "redirect" to the state you want.

```
.state('manager.staffDetail.view', {
    url:'/view',
    templateUrl: 'views/staff.details.html',
    controller: 'YourController'
})

app.controller('YourController', ['$state',
function($state) {
    $state.go('manager.staffDetail.view.schedule');
}]);
```

You can write you controller right in the state config for short.

Comment: I tried that, but it will double load controllers, resolves and anything that is onStateChange. I eneded up just using $urlRouterProvider.when('/app/service', '/app/service/list')

Comment: will this load only twice or infinite times as the child state also invokes the parent state again as there we are redirecting again to child.

Comment: If your navigation has the parent sref, it will not work on subsequent clicks - only on the initial controller load.

Answer (score 3):

I changed 'manager.staffDetial.view' to an abstract state and left the url of my default child state to blank ''

```
// Staff
.state('manager.staffList',    {url:'^/staff?alpha',      templateUrl: 'views/staff.list.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}, controller: 'staffListCtrl'})
.state('manager.staffDetail',   {url:'^/staff/{id}', templateUrl: 'views/staff.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}, controller: 'staffDetailsCtrl'})
.state('manager.staffDetail.view',   {url:'/view', abstract: true, templateUrl: 'views/staff.details.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
    .state('manager.staffDetail.view.schedule', {url:'', templateUrl:'views/staff.view.schedule.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
    .state('manager.staffDetail.view.history', {url:'/history', templateUrl:'views/staff.view.history.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
    .state('manager.staffDetail.view.log', {url:'/log', templateUrl:'views/staff.view.log.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
    .state('manager.staffDetail.view.files', {url:'/files', templateUrl:'views/staff.view.files.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
.state('manager.staffDetail.edit',   {url:'/edit',  templateUrl: 'views/staff.edit.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
```

Comment: So you basically did exactly what I had suggested... why not give my answer the correct checkmark then? So I can get the rep points.

Comment: I'm not sure you know what the word "exactly" means. However, your code example used the routeProvider method. I chose to not use that at all and instead keep the solution inside the state manager. This way the code stays clean and does not add any unnecessary extra lines of code. Your example was a possible answer, but not the most acceptable answer.

Comment: It seemed as though everything you did, I had mentioned (though, yes, the code in my example was unneccessary).
ME: "...you should set it to an abstract state."
YOU: "I changed 'manager.staffDetial.view' to an abstract state..."
ME: "Or a different option is give schedule an empty URL."
YOU: "...and left the url of my default child state to blank". Seriously no hard feelings though, I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: Sorry, your answer was confusing, and not on point. After reading your explanation I see that you gave the separate options, and that in the end if I sort of combined your first and last option and left out the middle suggestion I would have a solution. I guess I see where you are going, but I'm not sure it would help the next reader if I marked yours as the answer. If you want to edit your answer and clear up your answer I'll be happy to give you the answer.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I wrote the answer from my phone... :P I have cleaned up the answer, I hope it makes more sense now. Also I notice that if I search ui-router on Google this thread is the fourth result, so it **is** important that we have it be very clear.

Comment: I made you the answer, how about plus one my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

In "angular-ui-router": "0.2.13", I don't think @nfiniteloop's redirect solution will work. It worked once I had rolled back to to 0.2.12 (and may have had to put the $urlRouterProvider.when call before the $stateProvider?)

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285671/1098564

and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27131114/1098564 for a workaround (if you don't want to go back to 0.2.12)

as of Nov 28 2014, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1584 indicates that it should work again in 0.2.14

Answer (score 1):

This is late but all the answers here don't apply to the latest version of angular-ui-router for AngularJS. As of *that* version (specifically [@uirouter/angularjs#v1.0.x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@uirouter/angularjs) you can just put `redirectTo: 'childStateName'` in the second param of `$stateProvider.state()`. For example:

```
$stateProvider
.state('parent', {
  resolve: {...},
  redirectTo: 'parent.defaultChild'
})
.state('parent.defaultChild', {...})
```

Here is the relevant doc section: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-hook-redirectto

Hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

here is a very simple and transparent alternative by just modifying parent state in ui router:

```
  .state('parent_state', {
    url: '/something/:param1/:param2',
    templateUrl: 'partials/something/parent_view.html',  // <- important
    controller: function($state, $stateParams){
      var params = angular.copy($state.params);
      if (params['param3'] === undefined) {
        params['param3'] = 'default_param3';
      }
      $state.go('parent_state.child', params) 
    }
  })

  .state('parent_state.child', {
    url: '/something/:param1/:param2/:param3',
    templateUrl: '....',  
    controller: '....'
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [angular-ui-router-default](https://github.com/nonplus/angular-ui-router-default) and add the `abstract` and `default` options to the parent state:

...

```
.state('manager.staffDetail.view', {abstract: true, default: '.schedule', url:'/view',  templateUrl: 'views/staff.details.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
  .state('manager.staffDetail.view.schedule', {url:'/schedule', templateUrl:'views/staff.view.schedule.html', data:{activeMenu: 'staff'}})
```

...

Note: for this to work, the parent template must have `<ui-view/>` somewhere in it.