# How to set a default state with Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using states to change data in a table.
URLs are of the form `/zone/:zoneCode`.
However, when just `/zone` is accessed I want it to default to a certain `zoneCode`.

This is my code:

```
.state('zone',
{
    url:'/zone',
    controller:'ZoneController',
    templateUrl:'views/zone.html'
})
.state('zone.code',
{
    url:'/:zoneCode',
    templateUrl:function(stateParams)
    {
        return 'views/zone-codes/'+stateParams.zoneCode+'.html';
    }
}
```

The template loaded for each subview contains a table that displays data.
When no `zoneCode` is present in the URL, the table doesn't exist because the `ui-view` didn't know to load a `templateUrl`.

How can I set a default for the parent state?

Thanks.

Comment: What? It's not even close to duplicate... That question is about setting a fallback for unmapped URLs, my question is about changing a child state from a controller.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Although the question is quite old, I would still like to provide an answer as I had the same problem. The answer can be found [in this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001589/angularjs-ui-router-default-child-state). To apply that answer to your case:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/zone','/zone/'+zoneCode);
```

The urlRouterProvider checks to see if the url is [yoururl]/zone. If this is the case, it will redirect to the [yoururl]/zone/zoneCode, with the zoneCode as the one you specified.

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Thanks, Ivor. [extra chars]

Comment: +1 @IvorG I have also seen examples where the app.config begins `  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");` (change as appropriate)

Comment: also, fyi, if using this solution, the parent must not be abstract. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/497

Comment: @Noremac any parent, or just the immediate parent?

Answer (score 15):

You can also this, it'll handle routes that don't exist by redirecting to a default route set by you.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider.state("zone", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "views/zone.html",
});
```