# Have parent state default to child state using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this state structure:

```
.state('places',
{
    url:'/places',
    controller:'PlacesController',
    templateUrl:'views/places.html'
})
.state('places.city',
{
    url:'/:city',
    templateUrl:function(stateParams)
    {
        return 'views/places/'+stateParams.city+'.html';
    }
});
```

It works nicely except when the URL is simply `/places` without a city after it.
How can I have a default value for `templateUrl` in the child state?

I'm thinking the best way would be to set the ui-view from `PlacesController`, however that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, didn't have syntax highlighter set. Should be clean to read now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs ui-router default child state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001589/angularjs-ui-router-default-child-state)

Comment: Must see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29491412/2790983

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default child view with Angular UI Router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975094/how-to-set-default-child-view-with-angular-ui-router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the Angular-UI Wiki page:

> There are three main ways to activate a state:
>
> 1. Call $state.go(). High-level convenience method.
> 2. Click a link containing the ui-sref directive.
> 3. Navigate to the url associated with the state.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state

Comment: This answer shouldn't be accepted. It doesn't answer the question, which is about defaulting to a child state when a parent state is invoked.

Comment: +1 for the answer, I had the same question as the OP and it would seem invoking a child from a parent is not the right thinking, simply accessing the child route has the same effect with no thinking involved.

Comment: this is not a solution for delegating a state by it's child!

Answer (score 15):

Try defining another child state with the URL set to an empty string:

```
.state('places.default', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: '...'
}
```

Then add `abstract: true` to the parent state.

Comment: Hm, that's clever. I'd be happy if there was a method to change `ui-view` template URL directly though.

Comment: I don't know of any such function in ui.router.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. [extra chars]

Comment: While this solution works great, it won't work in combination with the latest version of ui-sref-active (from master). places.city won't be a parent of places.default for instance.

Answer (score 7):

Without needing any change in your states configuration, you can put your default template directly between the `ui-view` tags in your HTML:

```
<!-- places.html -->
<div ui-view>
  <h1>Please choose a place</h1>
</div>

<!-- london.html -->
<h1>London is amazing!</h1>
```

Now when you navigate to `/places`, you will see the "Please choose a place" message, and when you navigate to `/places/london`, you will see "London is amazing!".

Answer (score 1):

as stated by Aaron you can use **$state** to navigate to a default child state but here there is a catch  say suppose you have more than 1 child :

```
    .state('places',
    {
        url:'/places',
        controller:'PlacesController',
        templateUrl:'views/places.html'
    })
    .state('places.city',
    {
        url:'/:city',
        templateUrl:function(stateParams)
        {
            return 'views/places/'+stateParams.city+'.html';
        }
    })  
    .state('places.child2',
    {
        url:'/:city2',
        templateUrl:function(stateParams)
        {
            return 'views/places/'+stateParams.child2+'.html';
        }
    });
```

and in you parent controller **PlacesController**  you have **$state.go(places.city)** then whenever the parent controller i.e. PlacesController is invoked you will be redirected to city state. 
So if someone is on child2 state and presses a refresh button then parent controller will be invoked and he will be redirected to city which is not what you want!

**ANS:** So you can check for the current state before doing a redirection i.e. if the person is in parent state then redirect to any default child state but if the person is in any of the child states then do not do the redirection in the parent controller :-

```
 if($state.current.name == "places"){
     $state.go('places.city');
 }
```

hope this helps!

Comment: as comment, the second code block bust be in the `PlacesController`

Answer (score 1):

Use resolve on the parent state

```
.state('places',
{
    url:'/places',
    resolve: { default: function($state) {
      if ($state.is('places')) $state.go('places.city', { url: 'london'})
    }}
    controller:'PlacesController',
    templateUrl:'views/places.html'
})
.state('places.city',
{
    url:'/:city',
    templateUrl:function(stateParams)
    {
        return 'views/places/'+stateParams.city+'.html';
    }
});
```

Check for syntax error, I'm used to coffeescript :)