# How to set default child view with Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parent-child, angular-ui

Let's say I have the following 3 Angular UI Router states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('adminCompanies', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/admin/companies",
        template: '<div ui-view class="viewContainer" autoscroll="false" />'
    })
    .state('adminCompanies.list', {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: 'app/admin/companies/companies.list.html',
        controller: 'AdminCompaniesController'
    })
    .state('adminCompanies.detail', {
        url: "/:companyId",
        templateUrl: 'app/admin/companies/companies.detail.html',
        resolve: {
            company: function(Model, $stateParams) {
                return Model.get("/admin/companies", $stateParams.companyId);
            }
        },
        controller: 'AdminCompanyDetailController'
    })
```

If the `adminCompanies` is transitioned to directly, how can I tell Angular UI Router to go to the `adminCompanies.list` state instead?

Ideally, what I'd like to is something like:

```
$stateProvider.when('adminCompanies', 'adminCompanies.list');
```

In my code, I then want $state.go('adminCompanies') to be equivalent to $state.go('adminCompanies.list')

Comment: I guess it should be `$location.path('/admin/companies')`.

Comment: Does the template within the `adminCompanies` state contain a `ui-view` directive?

Comment: @DavidAntaramian Yes. I reuse a basic <div ui-view autoscroll="false" class="..."> so often, that is what `Templates.viewsContainer()` is for.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As your application is currently set up, you should not need any explicit logic for this. When a sub-state has an empty `url` property,  it becomes active at the same time its parent state becomes active. Any template for the sub-state is inserted into the `ui-view` directive provided by the parent state's template. The Angular UI [sample application](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts) addresses this type of architecture: when the `contacts` state is navigated to, its [template](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/contacts.html) provides the navigation layout as well as a distinct `ui-view` for its sub-states; because the `contacts.list` state has a `url` property of `""`, it is automatically loaded when its parent state, `contacts` is navigated to. This is documented in the application's [comments](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/states.js#L110):

> Using an empty url means that this child state will become active when its parent's url is navigated to. Urls of child states are automatically appended to the urls of their parent. So this state's url is '/contacts' (because '/contacts' + '').

Now, assuming for one reason or another that you **never** wanted your parent `adminCompanies` state to become active. In this case, you can make that state an [*abstract*](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#wiki-abstract-states) state like so:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('adminCompanies', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/admin/companies",
        template: '<div ui-view class="viewContainer" autoscroll="false" />'
    })
    .state('adminCompanies.list', {
        url: "/list",
        templateUrl: 'app/admin/companies/companies.list.html',
        controller: 'AdminCompaniesController'
    })
    .state('adminCompanies.detail', {
        url: "/:companyId",
        templateUrl: 'app/admin/companies/companies.detail.html',
        resolve: {
            company: function(Model, $stateParams) {
                return Model.get("/admin/companies", $stateParams.companyId);
            }
        },
        controller: 'AdminCompanyDetailController'
    })
```

*Note the addition of the `abstract: true` addition on the 3rd line and the explicit state url of `/list` for `adminCompanies.list`*

This tells Angular-UI that it should treat this state as if doesn't exist for URL navigation purposes. It will still become active when you navigate to sub-states though, so it will still use the URL you provide to prefix the URL of sub-states. But if you try navigating to it from another state, it will act as if the state doesn't exist. For this reason, you will also need to add handling for unmatched URLs using `$urlRouteProvider`.

A basic use of `$urlRouteProvider` might look like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")
```

That just redirects all calls to non-existent states to the state with the URL of "/". This assumes you have one. However, because someone might be trying to navigate to the list view but they are navigating to `/admin/companies` directly, you should probably have a handler like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when("/admin/companies", "/admin/companies/list");
```

Which one you use depends on the architecture of your application, but it seems that for your current needs you shouldn't have to do anything. If your specifications change, the abstract state might come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [ui-router-default](https://github.com/nonplus/angular-ui-router-default) - a module where default child states are defined in the parent state by setting `abstract: ".defaultChild"`.

This has the benefit of being able to use `ui-sref="parent"` and `$state.go("parent");` (which was important for me when dynamically creating a navbar).

NB: Both this and David's solution only work if the parent state is abstract - i.e. the parent cannot be active without a child being active - which should be the case when we want to have a "default" child view.

(See also the ui-router team's relevant discussion [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/27).)

Answer (score 1):

In version **1.0.0alpha0** they finally make it possible! Not child for abstract states, new **$transitionsProvider**, in which you could define **onBefore** hook. You can change the behaviour depends on state options.

For example you can change "abstract" param behaviour:

```
 $transitionsProvider.onBefore({
    to: state => !!state.abstract
  }, ($transition$, $state) => {
    if (angular.isString($transition.to().abstract)) {
      return $state.target($transition.to().abstract);
    }
  });
```

and use it like so:

```
  abstract: 'abstract2.foo',  //use not boolean but exact child state
```

[code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vOJlRv9V7fX9G8TNqfKf?p=preview)

was taken from:
[ui-router: Default child for abstract state](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2016/05/ui-router-default-child-for-abstract-state/)