# how to make a default nested state for a non abstracted state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router as follow:

3 main states `home`, `profile` and `settings` like this:
[image]

The 2nd state `profile` have 2 nested states `profile.about` and `profile.main`
[image]

I need that the profile state clickable on the index page loads the profile view and redirects to the default nested state which is `profile.about` here

[image]

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pUidlMhKlmQf9VFWRL16?p=preview) with what I got so far.

I'm aware of this solutions:

- [how to set up a defaultindex child state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state)
- [how to set default child view with angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975094/how-to-set-default-child-view-with-angular-ui-router)

And others but all require an abstract parent which is unclickable hence abstract.

So, to summaries my question is how to make a nested default view for a non abstracted state?

Comment: Check this Q & A http://stackoverflow.com/a/27131114/1679310 pluns the issue with latest UI-Router version

Comment: Thanks, that did it would you consider posting an answer instead of a comment so I can accept it and mark this as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comment, solution here would usually be with the .when() defintion as desribed here:

- [Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider .when not working *anymore*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23658846/1679310)
- [Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider .when not working when I click <a ui-sref="...">](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27120308/1679310)

In version before 2.0.13 we could use the native solution like this *(myService is a place for some default value... not needed if no params)*:

```
var whenConfig = ['$urlRouterProvider', function($urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider
      .when('/app/list', ['$state', 'myService', function ($state, myService) {
            $state.go('app.list.detail', {id: myService.Params.id});
    }])
    .otherwise('/app');
}];
...
app.config(whenConfig)
```

But after a fix in version 2.0.13 this is not working, but we can make it with this workaround:

```
var onChangeConfig = ['$rootScope', '$state',
 function ($rootScope, $state) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {    
    if (toState.name === "app.list") { 
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('app.list.detail', {id: 2});
    }
  });

}]
```

See also this bug report for some other examples: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1584

Comment: The later version of the solution works for me, but it makes protractor timeout.