# Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-router

I'm creating a tab based page which shows some data. 
I'm using UI-Router in AngularJs to register states.

My aim is to have one default tab open on page load. Each tab have sub tabs, and I would like to have a default sub tab open when changing tabs.

I was testing with `onEnter` function and inside I'm using `$state.go('mainstate.substate');` but it seems not to work due to loop effect issues (on state.go to substate it calls its parent state and so on, and it turns into a loop).

```
$stateProvider

.state('main', {
  url: '/main',
  templateUrl: 'main.html',
  onEnter: function($state) {
    $state.go('main.street');
  }
})

.state('main.street', {
  url: '/street',
  templateUrl: 'submenu.html',
  params: {tabName: 'street'}
})
```

Here I created a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/I88iqp7bElh1wNgBGU9f?p=preview).

For now everything works, except that I don't have the default tab open and that's exactly what I need.

Thank you for your suggestions, opinions and ideas.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

**Update:**
1.0 Onwards Supports redirectTo out of the box.

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#redirectto

---

I created [an example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/I88iqp7bElh1wNgBGU9f?p=preview).

This solution comes from a nice "Comment" to an an issue with redirection using `.when()` *(https://stackoverflow.com/a/27131114/1679310)* and **really cool solution for it *(by Chris T, but the original post was by yahyaKacem)***

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1584#issuecomment-75137373

So firstly let's extend main with redirection setting:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      url: '/main',
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      redirectTo: 'main.street',
    })
```

And add only this few lines into run

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params, {location: 'replace'})
      }
    });
}]);
```

This way we can adjust any of our states with its default redirection...Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/I88iqp7bElh1wNgBGU9f?p=preview)

EDIT: Added option from comment by @Alec to preserve the browser history.

Comment: This seems to clobber the back button.

Comment: @Swordfish0321 to fix the back button, make this small change:
`$state.go(to.redirectTo, params, {location: 'replace'});`
This will cause the new state to replace the previous state (ie the one we're being redirected from) in the history.
See docs for $state.go: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: Just wanted to add on that this was real close to what I wanted to do, but I wanted the default URL instead of replacing it, this was easily accomplished by changing `'$stateChangeStart'` to `'$stateChangeSuccess'`

Comment: ui-router 1.0 has built in support for this: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-hook-redirectto

Answer (score 21):

In fact even if this solution proposed by **[Radim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679310/radim-k%C3%B6hler)** did exactly the job, I needed to remember every tab's sub tab (state).

So I found another solution which do the same thing but also remembers every tab substate.

I all have to do was to install [ui-router-extras](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras) and use the [deep state redirect](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/dsr) feature:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('main.street', {
     url: '/main/street',
     templateUrl: 'main.html',
     deepStateRedirect: { default: { state: 'main.street.cloud' } },
  });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

As of [version 1.0](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#redirectto) of the ui-router it supports a `redirectTo` property. For example:

```
.state('A', {
  redirectTo: 'A.B'
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Since version 1.0 of ui-router, a default hook has been introduced using *IHookRegistry.onBefore()* as demonstrated in the example **Data Driven Default Substate** in http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/feature-1.0/interfaces/transition.ihookregistry.html#onbefore

```
// state declaration
{
  name: 'home',
  template: '<div ui-view/>',
  defaultSubstate: 'home.dashboard'
}

var criteria = {
  to: function(state) {
    return state.defaultSubstate != null;
  }
}
$transitions.onBefore(criteria, function($transition$, $state) {
  return $state.target($transition$.to().defaultSubstate);
});
```

Comment: This sort of work for me, although, I had to tweak it (also using ES6) `$transitions.onBefore({ to: state => state.defaultSubstate != null }, trans => trans.router.stateService.target(trans.to().defaultSubstate));`

Answer (score 4):

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.when("/state","/state/sub-state");

    })
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation as to what this does and why it's better than the already existing answers?

Comment: This solution is the easiest and worked well for me.

Comment: This is the best answer by far.   More concise than using change events.  No need to add packages.   I don't know how that's not clear to anybody.  I don't know how the accepted answer got upvoted so much.

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes here for an answer regarding how to implement a simple redirect for a state and, as it happened to me, doesn't have the opportunity to use the new router...

Obviously again if you can, @bblackwo answer is great:

```
$stateProvider.state('A', {
  redirectTo: 'B',
});
```

If you can't then just manually redirect it:

```
$stateProvider.state('A', {
  controller: $state => {
    $state.go('B');
  },
});
```

I hope it helps!