# ui-router default child state not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm testing `UI-Router` nested state, but I'm not able to set default state in parent/child scenario, please help.

**libraries:**

- angular 1.3.15
- ui router: 0.2.15

navigation path:

```
/ - home
/settings - parent state/page
/settings.default - child 1
/settings.mail - child 2
/settings.phone - child 3
```

**expected behavior:**

when navigating to `/settings`, the default child 'general' state/page should be triggered/loaded

**actual behavior:**

If I set 'settings' state 'abstrat: true', there will be error:

```
Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'settings'
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3143)
    at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3068)
    at angular-ui-router.js:4181
    at angular.js:16299
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4924)
    at angular.js:5312
```

If I remove 'abstrat: true', there's no error, but when i navigate to /settings, default child state/page - general state not triggered, settings.html displayed but  not loaded

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('test',['ui.router','sails.io'])     //config routing
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider',
        function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');    
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
        controller: 'IndexController'
    })
    .state('settings', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/settings',
        templateUrl: 'views/settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsController'
    })
    .state('settings.general', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'views/settings/general.html',
        controller: 'SettingsController'
    })
    .state('settings.mail', {
        url: '/mail',
        templateUrl: 'views/settings/mail.html',
        controller: 'SettingsController'
    })
    .state('settings.phone', {
        url: '/phone',
        templateUrl: 'views/settings/phone.html',
        controller: 'SettingsController'
    });
}]);
```

**views/settings.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><a ui-sref=".general">General</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a ui-sref=".phone">Phone</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a ui-sref=".mail">Mail</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From ui-router wiki "An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/THIAccJ4Piy86Myvbyff?p=preview)

This would work, but just with `url` navigation, i.e. **`href`**:

```
  <a href="/settings"> // will work
```

But this will not - we cannot go to **`abstract`** state:

```
  <a ui-sref="settings">settings</a>
```

But based on this Q & A:

#### [Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310)

We can remove abstract and create default state handling like this. There is [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nNFHaKBzMV0bi2Dzprbj?p=preview)

```
// redirection engine
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    });
}]);
```

The parent stat adjustment:

```
.state('settings', {
    //abstract: true,
    redirectTo: 'settings.general',
    url: '/settings',
    ...
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nNFHaKBzMV0bi2Dzprbj?p=preview)

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy amazing UI-Router

Comment: This breaks the back button.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an older question, but I thought I'd add something in case it helps someone else:

Although you may not want to add a plugin to solve this problem, you should check out [UI-Router-Extras](https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home)

There is a feature included there called "Deept State Redirect". This allows any state to save the most recently activated substate so that when you transition away, then back, the same substate (child state) will be active.

The part that would help your problem is being able to define a default child state. You do that by adding the "dsr" parameter and setting the "default" to whatever your child state is.

```
function myRouterConfig ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider
    .state('parentState', {
        //Not in this file          
        parent: 'index', 
        sticky: true,
        //ui-router-extras deepStateRedirect option
        dsr: {  
            default: 'parentState.defaultChild'
        },
        url: '/parentState',
        views: {
            'main@index': {
                template: '<my-parentStateComponent>'
            }
        }           
    })
    .state('parentState.defaultChild', {
        url: '/defaultChild',
        views: {
            'child@parentState': {
                template: '<my-defaultChildComponent>'
            }
        }
    });
```

}