# Angular ui-router struggle

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

Well, I have this project, and ui-router is giving me hard times. I made a quick Plunker demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/imEErAtOdEfaMMjMXQfD?p=preview

So basically I have a main view, `index.html`, into which other top-level views get injected, like this `operations.index.html`. The pain in my brain starts when there are multiple named views in a top-level view, `operations.detail.html` and `operations.list.html` are injected into `operations.index.html`, which is in turn injected into `index.html`.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is the following behaviour:

1. When a user clicks `Operations` item in the navbar, a page with empty (new) operation is shown. The URL is `/operations`.
2. When they select an item in a list, the fields are updated with some data (the data is requested via a service, but for simplicity let's assume it's right there in the controller). The URL is `/operations/:id`.
3. If they decide that they want to create a new item, while editing a current one, they click `New operation` button on top of the list, the URL changes from `/operations/:id` to `/operations`.
4. No matter new or old item, the item `Operations` in the navbar stays active.
5. If the user is editing an item, it should be highlighted as active in the list, if they create a new item — `New operation` button should be highlighted, accordingly.

Now, check out the weird behaviour: go to `Operations` and then click `Operations` navbar item again. Everything disappears. The same happens if I do `Operations` -> select `Operation 1` -> select `New operation`.

Besides, please, check out the part where I try to get the `id` parameter:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  if (toParams) {
    if (toParams.id) {
      for (var i = 0; i < vm.operations.length; i++) {
        if (vm.operations[i].id == toParams.id) {
          vm.operation = vm.operations[i];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I am no expert, but it seems too long and complex to be true, especially for such a simple task as getting a request parameter. If I try to check on state change `$stateParams` the object is empty, hence this workaround. If I try to tamper with states in `app.js`, things change slightly, but there are always bugs like `Operations` navbar item losing its active state or other weird stuff.

I know that asking such general questions is uncommon in SO, but I really can't grasp the concept of the ui-router, and I can feel that I'm doing things wrong here, and I would really appreciate any help in pointing me in the right direction of how to properly use ui-router for my purposes. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [the updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tAa1Quql3sCCTeWo7QDy?p=preview)

I just used technique from this Q & A: [Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310)

I added the **`redirectTo`** setting *(could be on any state)*

```
.state('operations', {
      url: '/operations',
      templateUrl: 'operations.index.html',
      controller: 'operationsController as op',
      // here is redirect
      redirectTo: 'operations.new',
 })
```

and added this **`redirector`**:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    });
}]);
```

and also, I removed the redirection currently sitting in the `operationsController.js`:

```
angular.module('uiRouterApp')
  .controller('operationsController', function($state, $stateParams, $rootScope) {
    var vm = this;

    //if ($state.current.name === 'operations') $state.go('operations.new');
```

And that all above is just to keep the new state - without url. Because the solution would become much more easier, if we would just introduce `url: '/new'`:

```
.state('operations', {
  url: '/operations',
  ..
})
.state('operations.new', {
  //url: '',
  url: '/new',
```

Check the [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tAa1Quql3sCCTeWo7QDy?p=preview)

So, this way we gave life to our routing. Now is time to make the detail working. To make it happen we would need more - [there is another updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xIFOxR5K4SCVFWcukKaD?p=preview)

Firstly, we will get *brand new* `controller` to both child state views:

```
.state('operations.new', {
  url: '',
  views: {
    'detail': {
      templateUrl: 'operations.detail.html',
      controller: 'detailCtrl as dc',         // here new controller
   ...
})
.state('operations.detail', {
  url: '/:id',
  views: {
    'detail': {
      templateUrl: 'operations.detail.html',
      controller: 'detailCtrl as dc',         // here new controller
    ...
```

It could be same controller for both, because we will keep decision new or existing on the content of the `$stateParams.id`. This would be its implementation:

```
.controller('detailCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    var op = $scope.op;

    op.operation = {id:op.operations.length + 1};

    if ($stateParams.id) {
      for (var i = 0; i < op.operations.length; i++) {
        if (op.operations[i].id == $stateParams.id) {
          op.operation = op.operations[i];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
})
```

We keep the original approach, and set the op.operation just if **`$stateParams.id`** is selected. If not, we create new item, with **`id`** properly incremented.

Now we just adjust parent controller, to not save existing, just new:

```
  .controller('operationsController', function($state, $stateParams, $rootScope) {
    var vm = this;

    //if ($state.current.name === 'operations') $state.go('operations.new');

    vm.operation = {};

    /*$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
                    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      if (toParams) {
        if (toParams.id) {
          for (var i = 0; i < vm.operations.length; i++) {
            if (vm.operations[i].id == toParams.id) {
              vm.operation = vm.operations[i];
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });*/

    vm.save = function() {

      if(vm.operations.indexOf(vm.operation) >= 0){
        return;
      }
      if (vm.operation.name 
      && vm.operation.description 
      && vm.operation.quantity) {
        vm.operations.push(vm.operation);
        vm.operation = {id: vm.operations.length + 1};
      }
    };
```

Check the [complete version here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xIFOxR5K4SCVFWcukKaD?p=preview)

Comment: You are a life-saver. I really exhausted my intellectual mana to figure out the desired configuration of states settings like `abstract` and so on. What saved me is 1) adding a `redirectTo` setting and a `redirector`; 2) adding `controller` settings to states, since now `$stateParams.id` is updated on every route change (i.e. selecting an operation). Nothing stops us now from conquering the world _hehehe_ :D Cheers, mate!

Comment: If that is working, I am really very glad. Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir ;)