# Set default child of abstract nested state in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I use `ui-router`.
Here are my nested states:

```
$stateProvider
.state('books', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/books',
  controller: 'BooksCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books.html'
})
.state('books.top', {
  url: '/top',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books-top.html'
})
.state('books.new', {
  url: '/new',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books-new.html'
});
```

How can I set `books.new` state to be default child of the `books` abstract state, **so then when you hit `/books` ui-router redirects to `/books/new`?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/RMluXGP0z6CyHMjUvmet?p=preview)

We can use built in features. 1) default is such child state which has empty url:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('books', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/books/new',
      controller: 'BooksCtrl',
      ..
    })
    .state('books.new', {
      //url: '/new',
      url: '',
      ...
    })
    .state('books.top', {
      url: '^/books/top',
      ...
    });
```

And 2) to keep `/books` in place, we can use redirection

```
  $urlRouterProvider.when('/books', '/books/new');
```

And these links will work as expected:

```
// href
<a href="#/books">
<a href="#/books/new">
<a href="#/books/top">
//ui-sref
<a ui-sref="books.top">
<a ui-sref="books.new">
```

Check [it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RMluXGP0z6CyHMjUvmet?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$stateProvider
.state('books', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/books',
  controller: 'BooksCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books.html'
})
.state('books.top', {
  url: '/top',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books-top.html'
})
.state('books.new', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books-new.html'
});
```

**EDIT:** I know that's not very nice, but you can create additional state with same arguments except url:

```
var booksArgs = {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books-new.html'
};
$stateProvider.state('books.new', booksArgs);
$stateProvider.state('books.new_', angular.extend({}, booksArgs, {
    url: '/new'
}));
```

**Another solution** from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29491412/1265753):

In states configuration:

```
$stateProvider
.state('books', {
  url: '/books',
  controller: 'BooksCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books.html',
  redirectTo: '.new'
})
.state('books.top', {
  url: '/top',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books-top.html'
})
.state('books.new', {
  url: '/new',
  templateUrl: 'contents/books-new.html'
});
```

On module run:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params, { relative: to });
      }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: if I follow your solution, I'll get `/books` URL for the **new books** page. I need it to be `/books/new` and also be accessible through `/books`.

Comment: I am not use how will this work and as you said, it's not very nice. I'll try one thing, if it works I'll let you know

Comment: @MikeVayvala See [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29491412/1265753) too

Comment: @MikeVayvala made redirection relative, I think it will be more useful in multiple nested states. Did not test, hope it works