# Nested states UI Router

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state

I am struggling to get nested states working with UI router

I want a page to view a device to be have a URL like `/device/SERIAL_NUMBER/info` where

- `/device` is fixed
- `/SERIAL_NUMBER` is variable aka `:id`
- `/info` refers to a nested state

I have a number of nested states I want, but for simplicity I'm only showing a one state.  Note that for `info` it shares the same controller as the parent view, other nested views do not.

**State setup**

```
.state('device', {
    url: '/device/:id',
    templateUrl: '/views/devices/device.html',
    controller: 'viewDeviceController'
})
.state('device.info', {
    url: 'info',
    templateUrl: '/views/devices/device_info.html'
})
```

**My main HTML looks something like this**

```
<body>
   <header><h1>Title</h1></header>
   <div ui-view>
       <!-- This is where /views/devices/device.html goes -->
   </div>
```

**/views/devices/device.html looks like so:**

```
<div>General text about a device</div>
<div ui-view>
   <!-- This is where /views/devices/device_info.html should go -->
</div>
```

If I navigate to `/#/device/L340009` I see the main page and the `device.html`, I do not see `device_info.html` - this is expected but ideally I'd like the default to be to load the first route (info)

If I navigate to `/#/device/L340009/info` it redirects me to home (which is my `otherwise`) so something is wrong with the route

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url here should start with '/'

```
.state('device.info', {
    // instead of this
    // url: 'info',
    // we need this
    url: '/info',
    templateUrl: '/views/devices/device_info.html'
})
```

that will support url concatenation

```
'/#/device/L340009' + '/info' 
is '/#/device/L340009/info'
```

Comment: I feel stupid - that worked! How do I get `info` to act as the default route if one isn't specified?

Comment: Sorry, not fully sure about this "..How do I get info to act as the default route if one isn't specified?..." I do not fully understand. Are you asking about how to do default redirection if wrong state is provided? In case that yes, we can use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');` - check this plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/4pjoofCXq444kjXLqGx8?p=info

Comment: I already have an otherwise for the top level route, what I mean is if someone goes to `/device/XXXXX` how do I make them auto go to `/device/XXXXX/info`

Comment: I see... I will try to find some example ... This one I do like the most http://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow! Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir ;)