# ui-router: open state in new tab with target="_blank", params are lost

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, ui-sref

I'm doing an Angular app in which a table's rows has a button each, and on click of these buttons a new tab should be opened for the row that button is on.

I needed to pass parameters into the new tab created this way. I've declared the parameter in the state initialization:

```
.state('viewlisting', {
   url: "/listings/:id",
   params: {
     'action': '',
   },
   controller: 'ListingsController',
   templateUrl: "partials/listings/view_listing.html"
 });
```

and the button has something like this:

```
ui-sref='viewlisting({id:"+data+", action:"images"})'
```

The params are passed in, everything works as expected.

```
//URL: /#/listings/42
$state.params.action //returns "images"
$state.params.id //returns "42"
```

But adding `target="_blank"` to the `<a>` tag causes the $state.params object to return the following:

```
//URL: /#/listings/42
$state.params.action //returns ""
$state.params.id //returns "42"
```

I've searched for hours, I've looked at the ui-router documentation and the issue tracker for something that addresses my situation but I've found nothing.

Are state parameters not passed on `target='_blank'`'ed `ui-sref` links?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is any parameter which should be available outside of the current SPA context *(new window, new tab)* - it **MUST** be part of the url.

This will work:

```
.state('viewlisting', {
   // instead of this
   // url: "/listings/:id",
   // this will keep the action in a new window
   url: "/listings/:id?action",
   params: {
     'action': '',
   },
   controller: 'ListingsController',
   templateUrl: "partials/listings/view_listing.html"
 });
```

More details about params [How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25647454/1679310)

Comment: Thank you for this.. somehow I knew this was possible but I wanted to keep the action parameter from the URL. I just want to ask if there's a way where I can change the resulting url `/listings/42?action=images` to `listings/42`.

Comment: The answer should be clear now (I mean after my answer) - NO it is not possible. URL is only way how to talk to extern world. And that is new tab, new window or just a link send via email. All needed params must be embeded into url. Is it clear now?

Comment: You've made that clear quite well, I was asking how to change the URL written on the address bar to `listings/42` AFTER `/listings/42?action=images`. It's not as if I'm rejecting your answer, I just don't want to expose the parameter to the user, so I was thinking if I could just the change the URL AFTER the page loads.

Comment: Well, there are techniques how to apply redirect. E.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310 *(so you can swallow the params in the second state...)* 1) user will be navigating to some state with url params 2) on state change this is taken, converted into $state.go and passed to other state, without url params. That could be the way...

Comment: Thank you for the linked question! Will definitely try this. Thank you for your time also!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way without using the URL. You can use `LocalStorage` instead of the URL.

Use `ng-click` on the link tag and call a function. In the function put your parameters in `LocalStorage`. Then in `app.run` use `$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart")` and check if `LocalStorage` have parameters. Then get `params` and call `$state` with `params`.

```js
//in page controller: 
var openNewTab = function () {                  
                    localStorage.newTab = JSON.stringify({
                        state: "yourState",
                        params: {
                            param1: "someparam1",
                          param2:"someparam2"
                        }
                    });                  
                    window.open(document.location.origin);
                      
                }
 
 //angular app run config: 
angularApp.run(function($state){
if(localStorage.newTab){
   var newTab = JSON.parse(localStorage.newTab);
   localStorage.removeItem("newTab");
   $state.go(newTab.state, newTab.params);
   event.preventDefault();
}
})
```

```html
<a ng-click="openNewTab()" >open new tab</a>
```