# UI Router - Nested views have double slashes and redirect to root

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, state

I'm trying to edit a project so that it uses a root view/state, which holds all the other views/states inside it. Before, every page was it's own independent state which wasn't that great when I wanted to add something globally to all states as it would mean you'd have to use `$rootScope` too often.

So in `app.js` I've done this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
    controller: function($state) {
      $state.go('app.home');
    }
});
```

So my logic here is that I want to keep the same structure of the website and everything like that. So inside `app.html` I have just included `<div ui-view></div>` so that I can inject all the child states, and then on load I am just loading the `home` state which was originally just the homepage called on `'/'`.

So now, `app.home`is this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.home', {
    templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  });
```

No URL here as I'm just loading it from `app` anyway. And here is another page I've tested:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.test', {
    url: '/test',
    templateUrl: 'app/test/test.html',
    controller: 'TestCtrl',
    authenticate: true
  });
```

The routing works fine, and the views are loaded, but there are a couple of issues.

1. When navigating to `/test`, the URL will actually be `http://localhost:4000//test` with two slashes. I can force it to be one slash if I make the url just `test` in the `stateProvider`, but I don't think that's the correct solution.
2. If I reload the page from `/test` it will also just redirect me back to `http://localhost:4000/` and the root state.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to define empty url on the state app `url: '',` and configure `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app.home')`? This way slash won't be added to child views and `/` route will be handled as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `url` is built from all *parents* `url` definitions - plus current state's `url`. I.e.:

```
"\" + "\test" === "\\test"
```

In case, we want to have url without parent part, we can use this sign **`^`**:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.test', {
    url: '^/test',
    templateUrl: 'app/test/test.html',
    controller: 'TestCtrl',
    authenticate: true
  });
```

#### [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol '^'.
>
> ```
> $stateProvider
>   .state('contacts', {
>      url: '/contacts',
>      ...
>   })
>   .state('contacts.list', {
>      url: '^/list',
>      ...
>   });
> ```
>
> So the routes would become:
>
> - `'contacts'` state matches `"/contacts"`
> - `'contacts.list'` state matches `"/list"`. The urls were not combined because ^ was used.

So, going to '\test' without absolute routes (^) will in fact trigger the otherwise setting, and go to default state...

EXTEND: how to create default state UI-Router standard way - [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CTCOWBOoCjEbHmkcHrYi?p=preview)

```
    .state('app', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      abstract: true,
      //controller:  function($state) {
      //  $state.go('app.home');
      //}
    })
    .state('app.home', {
      url: "",
      ...
    })
    .state('app.test', {
      url: '^/test',
      ...
    })
```

check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CTCOWBOoCjEbHmkcHrYi?p=preview)

Comment: I tried using `^/test` instead and that works for that route, but problem number 2 still occurs where if I refresh the page, then it actually loads `/` instead.

Comment: Yep I'm using html5Mode

Comment: Then you've configured your server wrongly. You should be sure, that server is ready for handling these url requests... check it here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: It worked before when I had separate routes for `/main`, `/test` and `/some-route`. Only since applying these changes has it occurred?

Comment: I'm actually using `grunt serve` as the server, so I will have to look at how to deal with an Express server from within grunt.

Comment: It worked.. maybe. Hard to say, without any other information. But you for sure know - it is not UI-Router issue. It is related to your server. If you for a while turn of html 5 and use the ^ - you should confirm to yourself that client side is ok. And that will give you proof - server is an issue

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I turn off html5 and refresh the page, it will still redirect me to the root url. I will look into fixing it on the server side of things though!

Comment: I'm actually using the `angular-fullstack` generator, so it should come with the server settings out of the box. I'm thinking there is something wrong with my code seeing as it worked before I nested everything under the `app` state.

Comment: I would suggest to adjust your state def, as I showed in my extended answer. There is also working plunker. ... and in case, that you would really need to have app as non abstract - use this approach http://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310

Comment: Why not just make your app url to be ""?

Comment: @Shikloshi check this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state

Comment: Thanks, the redirectTo solution actually worked for me perfectly!

Comment: I would say that this is really far the best way how to introduce defaults.. good luck with UI-Router ;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler .. Thanks Radim, great stuff and a lot of clarifications for me.