# angularjs - ui-router - can we preload nested state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this in my `app.js`:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('actionplans', {
      url: "/actionplans",
      templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.html",
      //controller : 'ActionplansCtrl'
    })
    .state('actionplans.planning', {
      url: "/planning",
      templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.planning.html",
      //controller : 'ActionplansCtrl'
    })
    .state('actionplans.summary', {
      url: "/summary",
      templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.summary.html",
      //controller : 'ActionplansCtrl'
    })
```

How can I default load nest view action `'actionplans.summary.html'` when called actionplans.html?

Comment: you want to load other 2 htmls into first one?

Comment: You should define view parameter in actionplans. Then whenever you call actionplans you will get includet views. Here link http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want. What do you mean by preload? Cache? Default to `actionplans.summary`? Load one template in the other?

Comment: @MattWay Default load nest view `action plans.summary.html` when called `actionplans.html`.

Comment: I'm still unsure as to what you mean. What does when called `actionplans.html` mean? Do you mean when you go to url: `/actionplans` you want to actually load `/actionplans/summary`?

Answer (score 1):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fTgR6TafU0cRAvM0yKCe?p=preview)

The way which will

1. load some view inside of a parent - and stay on parent
2. allow child change it when navigating to child

is called [Multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views):

```
.state('actionplans', {
  url: "/actionplans",
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.html",
      //controller : 'ActionplansCtrl'
    },
    '@actionplans': {
      templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.summary.html",
      //controller : 'ActionplansCtrl'  
    }
  }
})
.state('actionplans.planning', {
  url: "/planning",
  templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.planning.html",
  //controller : 'ActionplansCtrl'
})
.state('actionplans.summary', {
  url: "/summary",
  templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.summary.html",
  //controller : 'ActionplansCtrl'
})
```

What we did above, is that we used **`views : {}`** object to define two views. First is targeting the `index.html` (the '') the second is targeting this state view target for children ( the '@actionplans').

```
  views: {
    '': { // index.html      
      ...    
    },
    '@actionplans': { // this targets the unnamed view for children
```

Read more about [absolute names here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

Another way, is to define some default redirection, but that will disable parent state as a real target (e.g. here [Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310))

Answer (score 0):

Here discuss about AngularJS Routing Using UI-Router, you will get enough idea about nested view and multiple view.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state).

```
 $urlRouterProvider.when('/actionplans', '/actionplans/summary');//<-- Add in this line
    $stateProvider
    .state('actionplans', {
      url: "/actionplans",
      abstract: true,/// <-- Add in this line
      templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.html",
    })
    .state('actionplans.planning', {
      url: "/planning",
      templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.planning.html",
    })
    .state('actionplans.summary', {
      url: "/summary",
      templateUrl: "pages/actionplans.summary.html",
    })
```

This will load nest view `actionplans.summary.html` by default when you call `/actionplans`. My apology that I did not make this clearer in my question so I post the answer here hopefully it will help someone else with the similar scenario.