# default child inside father in $stateprovider with typescript

Tags: typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I have an html page father with:

```
<div id="..." class="container">
   <pp-nav></pp-nav>
   <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

This is my controller with a father and two child:

```
export function routerConfig($stateProvider: angular.ui.IStateProvider, $urlRouterProvider: angular.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('gestionePeP', {
  url: '/gestionePeP',
  templateUrl: '.../gestionePeP/gestionePeP.html'
})
.state('gestionePeP.puntiAttivazione', {
  url: '/puntiAttivazione',
  templateUrl: '.../gestionePeP/puntiAttivazione.html'
})
.state('gestionePeP.gestioneContenuti', {
  url: '/gestioneContenuti',
  templateUrl: '.../gestionePeP/gestioneContenuti.html'
});
```

I want that when I go to the father page the stateprovider opens the father html page with the first child inside it.
How can I do it?

If I put a link inside a button in the father  with

```
ui-sref="gestionePeP.puntiAttivazione"
```

it opens the right page. But I want the same behaviour without any click.
I tried $state.go('gestionePeP.puntiAttivazione') but it goes in loop.
How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still far the best way I found is here:

#### [Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310)

just add these lines to some .run()

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    });
}]);
```

And extend state def with default **`redirectTo`**:

```
.state('gestionePeP', {
  url: '/gestionePeP',
  templateUrl: '.../gestionePeP/gestionePeP.html',
  // this will set redirect target
  redirectTo: 'gestionePeP.puntiAttivazione',
})
```

Check [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310) to se working plunker

EXTEND - how to make ng.ui.IState aware of the new property `redirectTo`?

Just add these lines to your code:

```
declare module angular.ui { export interface IState { redirectTo?: string; } }
```

Comment: redirectTo doesn't exist in type IState.

Comment: Not so difficult to make it part of `IState`, right? ;) Extended answer should show how to ;)

Comment: I don't know where to add the app.run function

Comment: Have you observed my plunker?

Comment: Yes but I don't have an app.js file

Comment: you can place it anywhere - as it is. Just, have an `app` variable or use angular.module("xxx")... the rest is working even with TS. And it could be placed in any file. once angular will load all the script, it will start to execute them in proper order. Firstly config, then run... I really do not see where is the issue.

Comment: Yes I found where to put the function and works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. Really! Enjoy mighty combination - angular, UI-Router and TypeScript ;)