# Angular ui-state with params type in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

### What I know

When using TypeScript with angular's ui state, I can provide "type assertion" with the UI-Router definitely typed library.

Using this, I can inject `$state` and have code similar to the following

```
function myCtrl($state: ng.ui.IStateService){
    // Some code
}
```

This gives me correct autocompletion/error reporting for `$state`'s methods.

So far, this is all fine.

### The problem

When I try to access a property of `params` like the following

```
function myCtrl($state: ng.ui.IStateService){
    // Trying to access a property of $state.params
    var example = $state.params.example;
}
```

**I get an error saying:**

> Property 'example' does not exist on IStateParamsService

because quite rightly, TypeScript doesn't know about this property.

### I considered trying:

*Defining my own Interface that extends `ng.ui.IStateService`*

```
interface IMyState extends ng.ui.IStateService{
    params: {
        example: string;
    };
}
```

Then set the type to *my* interface

```
function myCtrl($state: IMyState){
    var example = $state.params.example;
}
```

This gets rid of the error.

What is the correct type to use for `$state`?

Should I be defining my own interface like in my example?

Comment: *some inspiration how could you use TS and angularJS [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30501735/1679310)*

Comment: @RadimKöhler Thanks. I am using importing/exporting classes etc. I just tried to keep it simple for the sake of this question. Useful link though.

Comment: *Just a hint before you'll get your answer... I am using `class` with the `static $inject` notation... hint ;)*

Comment: @RadimKöhler I use `class` and `static $inject` notation in my production code. However, I still need to annotate the parameters correctly. I just thought using it here adds unnecessary confusion.

Comment: If you can show me some real.. broken .. code (best in plunker) I will help you... as far as I could... Other words... snippets in your question are not clear to me.. not sure what is not working. I do use UI-Router, TS and AngularJS... so some experience could be shared

Comment: @RadimKöhler I've edited the question to try make it a little clearer. I want to know what type `$state` should be defined as. When using `ng.ui.IStateService` I get the error posted in my question.

Comment: I think your approach is good. That is the way I do it and I don't see any other. Although a bit more 'untyped' will be if you declare it as `any`, this way you won't need to create an interface extra

Comment: Sorry, for not understand your issue at first look.. I hope my answer will show you how to.. good luck with UI-Router ;) (similar trick I applied here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33763652/1679310)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Typescript, we really can easily extend a contract, coming with `UI-Router` **.d.ts**.

So this is the original definition *(UI-Router d.ts. file)*:

```
// a state object
interface IStateService {
    ...
    params: IStateParamsService;
    ...
// params
interface IStateParamsService {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

And we can just introduce into our custom .d.ts these lines

```
declare module angular.ui
{
    export interface IStateParamsService { example?: string; }
}
```

And that will now give us ability to consume `$state` and its params with example:

```
MyMethod($state: ng.ui.IStateService)
{
    let x = this.$state.params.example;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of this!

Comment: Great to see that, enjoy UI-Router and TS ;)

Answer (score 3):

`$state.params` are of type `IStateParamsService` and if you look at [the type signature](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/angular-ui--angular-ui-router/interfaces/ng.ui.istateparamsservice.html) you can read that it is an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

> Indexable types have an index signature that describes the types we can use to index into the object, along with the corresponding return types when indexing.

The described type of `IStateParamsService` is

```
(key: string): any
```

which means something like, "you can store objects of type `any`(everything is an `any`) and read the objects by the key (or index or you-name-it, this is where the name indexable type comes from) of type `string`".

here some code:

```
// this gives us an object of type IStateParamsService
let params = $state.params;

// params is a indexable type
// we want the object stored at index 'example'
let example = params['example'];
// or
let example = $state.params['example'];
```

more informations about interfaces and types can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".