# Angular ui-view default / proper usage:

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

This is for a 'subset' view off of my main view where I have a tab bar (Map, Market and Charts). When clicking them, they are properly output in this tag via UiSref.

```
 <div ui-view name="inception2"></div>
```

The 3 views are defined in my routes file as posted below.

How can I default the view in uiViewName to tsView2? Currently I need to click in order to route. Again I have a router file set up that does have abstract states and all - this is only for a simple tab exercise in the existing project. Thanks!

```
.state('tsView1', {
  views: {
    'inception2': {
      templateUrl: 'client/templates/tsVview1.html'
    }
  } 
})

.state('tsView2', {
  views: {
    'inception2': {
      templateUrl: 'client/templates/tsView2.html'
    }
  } 
})

.state('tsView3', {
  views: {
    'inception2': {
      templateUrl: 'client/templates/tsView3'
    }
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution

[Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310)

Introduce a small engine, reading a setting **`redirectTo`**

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    });
}]);
```

And then apply the default *child* on its *parent*

```
.state('main', {
  redirectTo: 'tsView2',
  ...
  }
.state('tsView2', {
  parent: 'main'
  ...
  }
```

This, other words, requires the tsViews to be children... but I guess that it already should be true

> *This is for a 'subset' view off of my **main view** where I have...*

Answer (score 1):

Use `$urlRouterProvider` to configure the default route using the `otherwise` method

```
.state('tsView2', {
  url: '/tsview2',
  views: {
    'inception2': {
     templateUrl: 'client/templates/tsView2.html'
   }
  } 
})


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tsview2');
```

For details on `$urlRouterProvider`, see this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider

Comment: Aditya, My apologies - I didn't mention this is a one-off / subset in my existing project - I already use UrlRouteProvider otherwise to redirect on the main nav view. This UI View is a subset. I'll update with those details.