# Lazy-load certain files for routes that don't begin with `addin`

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

I have a website build by `AngularJS` and `angular-ui-router`. In `index.html`, I load a lot of `.js` and `.css` files.

Now, I realize that a part of these `.js` and `.css` files are not necessary for the routes like `https://localhost:3000/addin/...`. So I want to load them by `ocLazyLoad` only for routes like `https://localhost:3000/xxxxx/...` where `xxxxx` is not `addin`.

Does anyone how to accomplish that in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.state('xxxxx', {
    url: '/xxxxx',
    templateUrl: 'xxxxx.html',
    controller: function($ocLazyLoad) {
        $ocLazyLoad.load('xxxxx.module.js');
}
```

#### Update

As per what you asked in your comments, you can't have like `not` for `states`. You need to map `states` explicitly.

One way I can think for creating a state which is `not` `/addin`, is to first explicitly map them in `$stateProvider` and then redirect via some `redirect` state and then load modules which you want to **lazy load**.

Redirect states other than `addin` by doing [somthing like this for redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491079/redirect-a-state-to-default-substate-with-ui-router-in-angularjs)

Comment: Sorry, `xxxxx` is a general term which represents all the words except `addin`.