# UI Router: redirect to child state when navigating to abstract parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, states

In my music app, I have an ng-repeat on the top-level states of my app to create navigation links. One of the top-level states, called library, is abstract and has child states (which are navigable using tabs). Since I am using an ng-repeat, the abstract state has a directive of `ui-sref="library"`. However, it's not possible to navigate to an abstract parent state like that, instead I would need to write `ui-sref="library.albums"`. I am unable to do this because of the ng-repeat data coming directly from the state provider. How can I set a default child state on "library" so that whenever that state is visited, it redirects to the child?

Here's a diagram of my setup:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598000/have-parent-state-default-to-child-state-using-ui-router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `ui-sref` to link to an abstract state.

you could try something like:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams){
    if(toState.name == 'library'){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('library.albums', toParams);
    }
}
```

Rather than hardcoding each state redirection though, you could do something like:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('library', {
        url: '/library',
        data: {
            redirect: 'library.albums'
        }
    })
    .state('library.albums', {
        url: '/albums',
        data: {
            redirect: false
        }
    });

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams){
    if(toState.data && toState.data.redirect){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go(toState.data.redirect, toParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using 0.3.1 version of ui-router. And I don't know why but these solutions didn't work for me. Both of them!

Comment: If you use `toState.data.hasOwnProperty('redirect')` you won't need to do `redirect:false` on each state that doesn't redirect

Answer (score 11):

Found this question when I was looking for the same and then I found this on Angular UI-Router's FAQ page. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

### How to: Set up a default/index child state

1. Make the parent state abstract.

   ```
   $stateProvider
       .state('library', {
           url: '/library',
           abstract: true,
           template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
       })
       .state('library.albums', {
           url: '/albums',
           template: '<h1>Albums</h1>'
       });
   ```
2. Then if you give the child state an empty URL, it will match the exact parent's URL. However, if you want to keep a separate URL for the child, you can do this:

   ```
   $urlRouterProvider.when('/library', '/library/albums');
   ```

Read the given GitHub WIKI URL if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

In V1.0 of ui-router, the state parameter `redirectTo` was added (see [ui-router docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#redirectto)). This allows you to accomplish what you are looking for.

In your example you would not use `abstract: true` but would redirect to the `library.albums` state.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('library', {
        url: '/library',
        redirectTo: 'library.albums',
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
       
    })
    .state('library.albums', {
        url: '/albums',
        template: '<h1>Albums</h1>'
    });
```

with this you can use `ui-sref="library"`. This is very helpful because `ui-sref-active` will now work.