# ui-router how to set default state and "not found (404)" state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am migrating to ui-router in Angular 1.5 and I need to setup the state provider so when I enter the base URL for my app it goes to my home state, but if user enters some non-existing path, it shows a custom "404" template.

If I set the default state with `urlProvider.otherwise()`, I can no longer set the 404 template, and if I set up a state with `url: ""` and set up `urlProvider.otherwise()` for showing 404 template, then the base url will show the 404 template always.

How can I correctly configure this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/27958051/1679310

Comment: Are you using the legacy version or the 1.0 beta 3?

Comment: @RadimKöhler: I'll check it out now.

Comment: @Vi100: I'm using the current stable one (I think it's 0.3.1 or 0.3.2). Definitely not 1.0.

Comment: @CesarD I think that referenced Q & A should cover your needs.. good luck with UI-Router ;)

Comment: Use a state with url: '/' for the root, and otherwise for the rest

Comment: Indeed, that's what I just did based on Radim Köhler linked answer. I set my "home" state with url: '/', and set `$urlRouterProvider` like this: `$urlRouterProvider
  .when('', '/')
  .otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
   $injector.invoke(['$state', function ($state) {
    $state.go('notfound');
   }]);
  });`
Worked like a charm!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a 404 state. Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753156/404-page-in-angular-ui-router). If you have a different url for a home state than your base url, you can use

```
urlProvider.when('base-url', 'home-state-url');
```

Then you can remove the `urlProvider.otherwise()`