# AngularJS - Redirect parent route to child route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Parent template `Accueil` (which has no content) has two child templates `section1` and `section2`. This is the code used for the routing :

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/accueil/section1');
    $stateProvider
        .state('accueil', {
            url: '/accueil',
            templateUrl: 'pages/accueil.html'
        })
        .state('accueil.section1', {
            url: '/section1',
            templateUrl: 'templates/section1.html'
        });
        .state('accueil.section2', {
            url: '/section2',
            templateUrl: 'templates/section2.html',
            controller: 'sectionCtrl'
        })
```

This works fine if I go to `/accueil/secion1` or `/accueil/section2`. The problem is that when I go to `/accueil` (having no content) I don't know how to redirect it to the 1st child template. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you never want to actually go to state accueil? If so the cleanest solution would be to make the parent state abstract and change the url of the 1st child to '', as below:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/accueil');
$stateProvider
    .state('accueil', {
        url: '/accueil',
        templateUrl: 'pages/accueil.html',
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('accueil.section1', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1.html'
    });
    .state('accueil.section2', {
        url: '/section2',
        templateUrl: 'templates/section2.html',
        controller: 'sectionCtrl'
    })
```

Now if you navigate simply to /accueil you'll go to section1, and append a /section2 to get to section2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I had to change the default route to `.otherwise('/accueil');` for it to work since `/accueil/section1` doesn't exist anymore

Comment: My previous comment doesn't make any sense now :D

Answer (score 3):

The solution (by design in UI-Router) is explained here:

- [Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider .when not working *anymore*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23658846/1679310)
- [Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider .when not working when I click <a ui-sref="...">](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27120308/1679310)

we can use `.when()`, something like:

```
$urlRouterProvider
  .when('/accueil', ['$state', 'myService', function ($state, myService) {
        $state.go('accueil.section1');
}])
.otherwise('/app');
```

But with UI-Router 0.2.13 there is a bit different approach:

```
var onChangeConfig = ['$rootScope', '$state',
 function ($rootScope, $state) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {    
    if (toState.name === "accueil") { 
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('accueil.section1');
    }
  });

}]
```

And there is also a suggestion for 0.2.13 discussed here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1584

The plunker

- http://plnkr.co/edit/dcN7Qra6nY9ZTOGjgCvJ?p=preview

And the example

```
  $stateProvider.state('profile' , {
      url: "/about",
      templateUrl: "profile.html",
      redirectTo: 'profile.about'
  });

 app.run($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    });
  }
```

> See it in action in a fork of the above plunkr that @yahyaKacem posted:

Comment: I think I'm gonna go with @Joshua Ohana's answer :D