# Angularjs route redirect does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am working on a web site with Angularjs as my client side platform.
I am trying to do what has to be easy and straight forward to do, but for some reason does not work at this time.
The code for redirecting is:

```
      $urlRouterProvider
                .when('/notifications', '/notifications/items');

            $urlRouterProvider
                .when('/notifications/items', '/notifications/items/list');
```

but it does not work and I end up with the following url:

```
http://mydomain/#/notifications
```

here are the states I am using here:

```
 $stateProvider
                .state('notifications', {
                    url: '/notifications',
                    template: '<notifications-layout></notifications-layout>',
                    data: {
                        requiredPermission: 'notifications',
                        icon: 'suitcase',
                        title: 'send notifications'
                    }
                })
                .state('notifications.items', {
                    url: '/items',
                    data: {
                        title: 'notifications
                    },
                    template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
                })
                .state('notifications.items.list', {
                    url: '/list',
                    data: {
                        title: 'notifications
                    },
                    template: '<notifications-items></notifications-items>'
                })
```

I would love to know what am I missing , perhaps someone ran into this issue before?

Comment: can you show your states (`$stateProvider`)?

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey sure I've added it to my question thank you!!

Comment: you have the right code, here is [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oM34F9CoyzyBtipG5Z0a?p=preview) as an example. Something else is affecting it. Do you have any ideas which part of the code could be doing it?

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey No I do not know what can be causing this. Do you have any idea what can be the source of this kind of issue?

Comment: consider adding `ui-view` into every template like in my example. (In fact to support some older browsers, use `<div ui-view></div>`)

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey I am already doing this in notifications-layout. still the problem persist even in chrome...

Comment: if it can't reach it, it will not redirect you there. I suggested to add `ui-view` so that you can test at which step it fails to reach the destination

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey: I solved the issue. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer at the following link:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658846/angular-ui-router-urlrouterprovider-when-not-working-anymore)

For some reason, on my current project, the order of the $urlRouterProvider and $stateProvider on app.config is important for the UI Router to work...

Comment: is it possible that you have an older version of ui-router (0.2.X)? try updating it to 1.0.X

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey my version is:  v0.3.1