# Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider .when not working when I click <a ui-sref="...">

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

I have `.when('/center', '/center/question')` in my angular web app.

When I type `'/center'` in my browser it will redirect to `'/center/question'` as I expect but when I click the `<a ui-sref="center" href="#/center"></a>`, it won't redirect and just stay on the url `'/center'`.

There is no error in my console and I don't know why.

I see one similar issue here [Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider .when not working *anymore*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658846/angular-ui-router-urlrouterprovider-when-not-working-anymore).I try the answer but it still don't work for me.

Here is my coffeescript code:

```
whenConfig = ['$urlRouterProvider', ($urlRouterProvider) ->
  # default url config

  $urlRouterProvider
  .otherwise '/center'
  .when '/center', '/center/question'
]

stateConfig = ['$stateProvider', ($stateProvider) ->
  # nested url config

  capitalize = (s)->
    s[0].toUpperCase() + s[1..]

  mainConfig = ({
    name: name
    url: "/#{name}"
    templateUrl: "templates/#{name}.html"
    controller: "#{capitalize name}Ctrl"
  } for name in ['center', 'keywordList', 'keywordConfig', 'log', 'stat'])

  centerConfig = ({
    name: "center.#{name}"
    url: "/#{name}?page"
    templateUrl: "templates/center/#{name}.html"
    controller: "Center#{capitalize name}Ctrl"
  resolve:
    thead: (CenterService) ->
      CenterService.getThead @self.name
    data: (CenterService, $stateParams) ->
      CenterService.fetchItems @self.name, $stateParams.page
  } for name in ['question', 'answer', 'comment', 'article'])

  for singleConfig in mainConfig
    $stateProvider.state singleConfig

  for childConfig in centerConfig
    $stateProvider.state childConfig
]

app.config whenConfig
app.config stateConfig
```

Comment: Don't need to add href="" in your <a> tag, this job will be handled by ui-router...So replace this line <a ui-sref="center" href="#/center"></a> to <a ui-sref="center"></a> and check

Comment: @Asik I don't add href="", this is added by ui-router

Comment: oh Ok sorry! I misunderstood

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint at [line 3224](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/release/angular-ui-router.js#L3224) of ui-router in your browser and check if the transition promise is swallowing a syntax error or something. I've had that happen a few times.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a [new working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tiGDaajeDvyhEZ4dfe6c?p=preview) *(extending the [Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider .when not working *anymore*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23658846/1679310))*, which should be working with the version **`0.2.13+`**

### Previous solution

Until version **`0.2.12-`** we could use `$urlRouterProvider.when()`, suggested in documenation *(small cite)*:

> #### [How to: Set up a default/index child state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state)
>
> ...
>   if you want the 'parent.index' url to be non-empty, then set up a redirect in your module.config using $urlRouterProvider:

```
 $urlRouterProvider.when('/home', '/home/index');
```

So this was solution shown in the [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23658846/1679310) mentioned above:

```
var whenConfig = ['$urlRouterProvider', function($urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider
      .when('/app/list', ['$state', 'myService', function ($state, myService) {
            $state.go('app.list.detail', {id: myService.Params.id});
    }])
    .otherwise('/app');
}];
...
app.config(whenConfig)
```

Now - we cannot.

### UI-Router "FIX" in `0.2.13`

It is due to "FIX" *(which I am simply not sure about)*, mentioned in the release [0.2.13](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases)

> **Bug Fixes**
>   **$state:**
>   - ...
>   - Avoid re-synchronizing from url after .transitionTo ([b267ecd3](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/b267ecd348e5c415233573ef95ebdbd051875f52), closes [#1573](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1573))

And here is the [new code added in the urlRouter.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/b267ecd348e5c415233573ef95ebdbd051875f52#diff-c414428d49b83a7461facd34b0b53496R280):

```
if (lastPushedUrl && $location.url() === lastPushedUrl)
 // this line stops the corrent .when to work
 return lastPushedUrl = undefined;

lastPushedUrl = undefined;
```

This piece of code *is optimizing/fixing some other issue* ... but also, turning off the **`.when()`** functionality

### SOLUTION

As already mentioned, this brand new [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tiGDaajeDvyhEZ4dfe6c?p=preview) shows the way with version 0.2.13+. We just have to listen to state change, and if the state is "app.list" we can go to its detail with some id...

```
var onChangeConfig = ['$rootScope', '$state',
 function ($rootScope, $state) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {    
    if (toState.name === "app.list") { 
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('app.list.detail', {id: 2});
    }
  });

}]
```

Check the [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tiGDaajeDvyhEZ4dfe6c?p=preview)

Comment: You should also know, that because I am not sure, if this "new" behaviour of 0.2.13 is correct, I issued an issue https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1584. It could be that this workaround will be the way, but maybe not... we will see ;) Good luck with awesome UI-Router ;)

Comment: Got it ! Actually I also hope this could be more elegant, I subscribe the issue, thanks any way :)

Comment: UI-Router dev here. J22Melody, is your use case that you essentially want "a default substate of an abstract state?"  @RadimKöhler I'm considering your issue. I'll likely roll that commit back for 0.2.x (since it is what people currently expect), but reintroduce it in a later version when we have a better state-based-redirect solution.

Comment: @ChrisT Yes, I want "a default substate"

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in your controller too. I think it is cleaner than listening to state changes.

Example:

```
.controller 'YourControllerName', ($scope, $state) ->
    $state.go "center.question" if $state.is "center"
```

Comment: Am I the only one thinking CoffeeScript is completely unreadable?

Comment: This will only fire once when the controller is first initialised, but it will not be fired again and hence doesn't fix the problem. With this solution visiting `centre` will redirect to `center.question` but clicking a `ui-sref`of `center` will navigate to `center` without firing the above code again, leaving you in a blank view.