# angular ui-router active links

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have my states set up like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('sport', {
        url: "/:sport",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/sport.tpl.html',
        controller: 'DesignerController',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    })
    .state('sport.team', {
        url: "/team",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/team.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('sport.kit', {
        url: "/kit",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/kit.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('sport.design', {
        url: "/design",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/design.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('sport.refine', {
        url: "/refine",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/refine.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('sport.order', {
        url: "/order",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/order.tpl.html'
    });
```

and my **sport** template looks like this:

```
<div class="container designer">
  <div class="row designer-header">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h4>Your sport: <strong>{{ controller.sport.data.title }}</strong></h4>
          <h4>Your club: <strong>{{ controller.clubName }}</strong></h4>
          <h1>Team: <strong>{{ controller.teamName }}</strong></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-designer">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
              </div>

              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="designer-menu">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a ui-sref=".team">Your team</a></li>
                      <li><a>|</a></li>
                      <li><a ui-sref=".kit">Kit</a></li>
                      <li><a>|</a></li>
                      <li><a ui-sref=".design">Design</a></li>
                      <li><a>|</a></li>
                      <li><a ui-sref=".refine">Refine</a></li>
                      <li><a>|</a></li>
                      <li><a ui-sref=".order">Order</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="total pull-right">
              <p>Running total</p>
              <p>£ <span class="lead" ng-bind="controller.total"></span></p>
              <p><a href="#/">click to expand</a></p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row designer-body">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
```

I have 2 issues. When this page first loads, I want it to already have the child **sport.team** loaded in the **ui-view**, also, in the navigation I would like the current child to be an active link.

I have tried using some tutorials but they don't seem to fit my model.
Can someone help?

Comment: For 1. you need to either link directly to your .team state or make it the root (`url: '/'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for the default child selection I just simply changed my states to this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('sport', {
        url: "/:sport",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/sport.tpl.html',
        controller: 'DesignerController',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    })
    .state('sport.team', {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/team.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('sport.kit', {
        url: "/kit",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/kit.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('sport.design', {
        url: "/design",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/design.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('sport.refine', {
        url: "/refine",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/refine.tpl.html'
    })
    .state('sport.order', {
        url: "/order",
        templateUrl: '/app/sport/order.tpl.html'
    });
```

because **sport.team** doesn't have a url it becomes the active child. Also, I set the **abstract: true** on the parent. 
If you are navigating to the page from another, instead of using **sport** state, you should now use the child **sport.team** (in my case). Because child states inherit parent params and controllers, nothing is lost and everything continues to work.

---

For the second question about active links, this was actually really easy. I just added this line:

> > ui-sref-active="active"

to my navigation, which became this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="designer-menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".team">Your team</a></li>
        <li><a>|</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".kit">Kit</a></li>
        <li><a>|</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".design">Design</a></li>
        <li><a>|</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".refine">Refine</a></li>
        <li><a>|</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".order">Order</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and that is it. Everything now works.

Comment: I prepared a demo on the codepan according to @r3plica's solution: http://codepen.io/nerezo/pen/WbYBxY

Answer (score 0):

I [created working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6tSyMbf74ztaKvkJDyj4?p=preview) to show how to...

The way how to define the default child state could be:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 
  function ($rootScope, $state) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
   function(event, toState  , toParams
                   , fromState, fromParams) 
    {
      var isSport = toState.name =='sport' ;
      if(isSport)
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('sport.team', toParams);
      }
    });

}])
```

There are also other ways, check e.g.

- [Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider .when not working when I click <a ui-sref="...">](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27120308/1679310)
- [How to: Set up a default/index child state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state) (doc)

The way how to mark the current state is with the [ui-sref-active](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active) directive *(passing class to be applied)*

```
  <a ui-sref="sport({sport: 'hockey'})"
         ui-sref-active="selected">
  <a ui-sref="sport.team({sport: 'hockey'})" 
        ui-sref-active="selected">
  <a ui-sref="sport.kit({sport: 'hockey'})"
        ui-sref-active="selected">
```

If you like to mark only current child, not a parent, check the [ui-sref-active-eq](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active-eq)

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6tSyMbf74ztaKvkJDyj4?p=preview)