# Angualar ui-router automatically changing route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am getting issue during angular state change

My State configuration is as :

```
 function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('monetization', {
            url: '/monetization',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/monetization/monetization.html',
            controller: 'MonetizationCtrl'
        })
        .state('monetization.configurationGeneral', {
            url: '^/monetization/configuration/general',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/monetization/configuration/general/general.html',
            controller: 'MonetizationConfigurationGeneralCtrl',
        })
        .state('monetization.configurationVersion', {
            url: '^/monetization/configuration/version',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/monetization/configuration/version/version.html',
            controller: 'MonetizationConfigurationVersionCtrl',
        })
        .state('monetization.categorySearch', {
            url: '^/monetization/configuration/categorySearch',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/monetization/configuration/category/categorySearch.html',
            controller: 'MonetizationCategorySearchCtrl',
        })
        //Provider Configuration
        .state('monetization.providerList', {
            url: '^/monetization/provider/list',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/monetization/provider/providerList.html',
            controller: 'MonetizationProviderListCtrl',
        })
        .state('monetization.providerDetails', {
            url: '^/monetization/providerDetails/:providerId',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/monetization/provider/providerHistory.html',
            controller: 'ProviderHistoryCtrl',
            params: {
                providerId: null
            }
        });
}
```

I am automatically being redirected from **monetization.categorySearch** to **montetization.providerList**

I am not having any clue please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could confirm, that your state definition is ok AS IS - there is no REDIRECT turned on. So, it must be elsewhere - not in the `$stateProvider` configuration.

Check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oGdrvn53B70G6Jo03Pkp?p=preview) to see,  that all these links work as expected:

```
<a href="#/monetization">
<a href="#/monetization/configuration/general">
<a href="#/monetization/configuration/categorySearch">
<a href="#/monetization/provider/list">

<a ui-sref="monetization">
<a ui-sref="monetization.configurationGeneral">
<a ui-sref="monetization.categorySearch">
<a ui-sref="monetization.providerList">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oGdrvn53B70G6Jo03Pkp?p=preview)

*NOTE the small issue I see above is a typo "montetization.providerList"*

> I am automatically being redirected from **monetization.categorySearch** to **montetization.providerList**

*which should be monetization.providerList (not monte...), but it should not be related to that issue*

Suggestion, carefully check all the `event` hooks like:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {

    ...
    $state.go('monetization.providerList')

});
```

*(check e.g. this: [Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310))*

And also the .when setting on url provider

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/monetization/configuration/categorySearch'
                      , '/monetization/provider/list');
```

*(check e.g. this: [Angular UI-Router $urlRouterProvider .when not working when I click <a ui-sref="...">](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27120308/1679310))*