# Angular ui-router... Display default tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am arriving on `bookDetails` state form some other link. Here `bookDetails` state's template has links for different `tabs` (or templates). And associated controller `EditBookController` has a json file using which I am building forms in different `tabs` with states like `bookDetails.basic` and `bookDetails.publisher` which use parent `EditBookController`. It's working fine. How to directly display the default `bookDetails.basic` instead of making user click the link?         If I make `bookDetails` abstract(abbstract:true) and provide an empty link to `bookDetails.basic` I get following error `Cannot transition to abstract state 'bookDetails'`

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {              
              url:'/home',
              controller: 'HomeController',
              templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/Publisher_Home_Template.html'
          })
    .state('books', {
              url:'/books',
              controller: 'BooksController',
              templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/Book_Listing_Template.html'
          })          
    .state('bookDetails', {
              url : '/books/:b_id',                

              controller: 'EditBookController',                  
              templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/Product_Page_Template.html'
          }) 

    .state('bookDetails.basic', {
              url : '/basic',                  
              templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/tab1.html'
          }) 

    .state('bookDetails.publisher', {
              url : '/publisher',                  
              templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/tab2.html'
          })
```

[A plunk with similar problem. but code is different](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=EESJpJCxtn7Dt3po)  On clicking form it should land on the profile profile form.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001589/how-to-direct-user-to-a-child-state-when-he-is-transitioning-to-its-parent-state

Comment: But the solution is not working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AzDIFRSACqIxWOLuRTkS?p=preview)

There is similar question: [Redirect a state to default substate with UI-Router in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310)

The solution comes from a cool *"comment"* related to an issue with redirection using **`.when()`** *(https://stackoverflow.com/a/27131114/1679310)* and **really cool solution for it *(by Chris T, but the original post was by yahyaKacem)***

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1584#issuecomment-75137373

In the state definition I added ONLY one setting to **`bookDetails`** state, the: **`redirectTo: 'bookDetails.basic',`**. Let's have a look:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
.state('home', {              
          url:'/home',
          controller: 'HomeController',
          templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/Publisher_Home_Template.html'
      })
.state('books', {
          url:'/books',
          controller: 'BooksController',
          templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/Book_Listing_Template.html'
      })          
.state('bookDetails', {
          // NEW LINE
          redirectTo: 'bookDetails.basic',
          url : '/books/:b_id',
          controller: 'EditBookController',                  
          templateUrl: 'static/publisher/views/Product_Page_Template.html'
      }) 

.state('bookDetails.basic', {
          url : '/basic',                  
          templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/tab1.html'
      }) 

.state('bookDetails.publisher', {
          url : '/publisher',                  
          templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/tab2.html'
      })
```

And now - only these few lines will do the miracle:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 
 function($rootScope, $state) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    }
  );
}]);
```

This way we can adjust any of our states with its default redirection...Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AzDIFRSACqIxWOLuRTkS?p=preview)

Comment: There is for sure NO magic, no miracles ;) Please, check the 1) **Eventing system** of `UI-Router` here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#events-1 and the 2) data [Attach Custom Data to State Objects](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects). These together are here combined, whenever there is a state change (e.g. targeting the parent) we just check if such state in `data : {}` setting does not have preferred child. That's it. Really ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

From [Directing the user to a child state when they are transitioning to its parent state using UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001589/how-to-direct-user-to-a-child-state-when-he-is-transitioning-to-its-parent-state):

Either change the `bookDetails.basic` state to:

```
.state('bookDetails.basic', {
  url : '',                  
  templateUrl: '/static/publisher/views/tab1.html'
})
```

Or add the following routing:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/books/{b_id}', '/books/{b_id}/basic');
```

Comment: here is a similar plunk i have created... edit it  http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=hOUZg2P7uHv7gS2n

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `$state.go('bookDetails.basic')` inside  EditBookController. If I understood you< this will help.

Comment: This will always route to `bookDetails.basic` when the `bookDetails` controller is loaded...