# AngularJS UI Router nested view not loading content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've looked at *countless* examples of how to set this up. Many right here at SO. But nothing is working in my case. It's a very simple set of two views, one nested below the first. Second ui-view never loads...

Here is the simple `index.html`...

```
<body ng-app="d6Games">
   <div ui-view="home"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the simple child view, this is inside `home.html` template...

```
<div class="d6body bilbo">
     <div ui-view="content"></div>
</div>
```

Here are the simple states...

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: { 
        'home': {
            templateUrl: '/views/home.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('home.intro', {
    url: '/intro',
    views: { 
        'content': {
            templateUrl: '/views/game-intro.html'
        }
    }
})
```

The first `/views/home.html` template loads fine, as expected, however the child `/views/game-intro.html` never loads. It's just html and text and it's in the same folder as home.html.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/piQVWrXHhFiyabMulruq?p=info)

I just changed the template path (removed the leading '/'), and all is working *(however this was required for plunker, not sure about your environment and path settings)*:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'home': {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('home.intro', {
    url: '/intro',
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'views/game-intro.html'
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Check that in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/piQVWrXHhFiyabMulruq?p=info)

Comment: Ok, getting closer. I added the ui-sref links to the index.html, like you have. They actually do work when you click them. The game-intro.html loads as expected. However, why doesn't it load automatically, when the page loads, without having to click the home.intro link?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I added this line  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/intro');` and you can check in this forked plunker that it is working http://plnkr.co/edit/Vg3fmypcepEgkA8c40ju?p=preview .. the intro is initially working. In case, that you want to set some **child**  state to be default (instead of its parent) you should check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29579343/1679310 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/29491079/1679310