# Angular UI-Router nested views not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The template `<h1>HELLO</h1>` does not get loaded into the nested ui-view in analysis.client.view.html but the analysis.client.view.html file ui-view is loaded. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I also tried naming the nested ui-view but it didnt seem to help. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

#### oct.client.routes.js file

```
'use strict';

//Setting up route
angular.module('oct').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        // Projects state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('octAnalysis', {
            url: '/oct_analysis',
            templateUrl: 'modules/oct/views/sidebar.client.view.html'
        });

        $stateProvider.
        state('octView', {
                url: '/oct_view',
                templateUrl: 'modules/oct/views/analysis.client.view.html'
            })
            .state('octView.sidebar', {
                template: '<h1>HELLO</h1>'
            });

    }
]);
```

#### analysis.client.view.html file

```
<section class="analysis" ng-controller="AnalysisCtrl">
    <div id="sidenav-cntnr">
        <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left" md-is-open="" md-is-locked-open="menuPinned">
            Left Nav!
            <div id="pin-cntnr">
                <button ng-click="togglePinLeftMenu()">Pin</button>
                <button ng-click="closeLeftMenu()">Close</button>
            </div>
            <div ui-view></div>

        </md-sidenav>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle example of this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, its part of a huge project.

Comment: The entire project isn't necessary, just something that recreates the issue that we can see and test.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The `'octView.sidebar'` state doesn't have a URL defined.  It can't be activated.

Comment: @Amy I tried `url: ' '` but this didnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I went through this issue myself a few weeks back and this was what I came up with.  You might need to tweak it a little bit.  First, change your `.html` from this:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

to this named view:

```
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
```

Then change your state configuration as so:

```
$stateProvider.state('octView', {
    url: '/oct_view',
    views: {
        "": {
            templateUrl: 'modules/oct/views/analysis.client.view.html',
        }
        "sidebar": {
            template: "HELLO"
        }
    }
});
```

> Daniel Kobe: I tried url: ' ' but this didnt do anything

The thing is, you aren't actually using a child state.  States are activated when the URL matches, so the sidebar would only get activated when the browser's URL is `"/oct_view/ "` (notice the space).  You're really using one state, with multiple views.  You're wanting to direct users to a page represented by a state, and you want the sidebar to load as part of that state.  The sidebar *can* have its own controller.  See the [Angular UI documentation on named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) for more information.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: When I do this the page loads nothing. With no error message.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by looking at this post's selected answer [Directing the user to a child state when they are transitioning to its parent state using UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001589/how-to-direct-user-to-a-child-state-when-he-is-transitioning-to-its-parent-state)

I changed the routing code as follows:

```
    $stateProvider.
    state('octView', {
            url: '/oct_view',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'modules/oct/views/analysis.client.view.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('octView.sidebar', {
            url: '',
            template: 'HELLO'
        });
```