# Nested states in Ui-Router with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to have a common state with all the common views like the header and the sidebar, and a template where I would like to load different views that can change when the state is changing.

I have an index HTML file like this:

```
...
    <div ui-view="header"></div>

    <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div ui-view="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

While the AngularJS config is something like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('mainCommonState', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            header: {
                templateUrl: 'app/common/header.html',
                controller: 'headerCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            },
            sidebar: {
                templateUrl: 'app/common/sidebar.html',
                controller: 'sidebarCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            },
            content: {}
        },
        resolve: {
            apiEnvironment: function ($q, environmentApiService) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(environmentApiService.getApiEnvironment());
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    })
    .state('first-page-content', {
        url: '/first-page-content',
        parent: 'mainCommonState',
        views: {
            content: {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/first-page-content.html'
                controller: 'firstPageCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('second-page-content', {
        url: '/second-page-content',
        parent: 'mainCommonState',
        views: {
            content: {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/second-page-content.html'
                controller: 'secondPageCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('third-page-content', {
        url: '/third-page-content',
        parent: 'mainCommonState',
        views: {
            content: {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/third-page-content.html'
                controller: 'thirdPageCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
```

For some reason this is not working: I have an empty view instead of the 3 templates that I would like to show in the content `ui-view`.

If I define a template (even a blank template) inside the the abstract state, the view that is always showing is the one inside the abstract state `mainCommonState`.

**Where am I wrong?**

---

**1st Edit: UPDATE Following the first answer**

Following the suggestion from Chris T, I have updated my code, but there still something missing.

I have created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTQzGVpvsjKiM22NGo5v?p=preview) so you can help me fixing the issues.

---

**2nd Edit**

Following the suggestions from Chris T, I have updated the code using the absolute path for the `content` view and now the contents are switching correctly.

I have updated the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oTQzGVpvsjKiM22NGo5v?p=preview) accordingly to that and introduced a new level of nesting view (tabs in the first page), and I would like to have the first tab active when the first page content is loaded.

If I follow [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001589/directing-the-user-to-a-child-state-when-they-are-transitioning-to-its-parent-st?rq=1) and set empty the url of the first page and set it to the first tab instead, this is not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your views are targeting the wrong named `ui-view`.

```
.state('second-page-content', {
     url: '/second-page-content',
     parent: 'mainCommonState',
     views: {
         content: {
             templateUrl: 'app/components/second-page-content.html'
             controller: 'secondPageCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'vm'
         }
     }
 })
```

In this snippet, it targets the ui-view named `content` from the parent state which is `mainCommonState`.  However, the `content` ui-view was not created in the `mainCommonState`.  It was created in the root template.

Change your view declarations to target the view at the correct state, for example this targets the `content` view at the root state (which is named empty string):

```
.state('second-page-content', {
     url: '/second-page-content',
     parent: 'mainCommonState',
     views: {
         'content@': {
             templateUrl: 'app/components/second-page-content.html'
             controller: 'secondPageCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'vm'
         }
     }
 })
```

In ui-router 1.0 and higher you can also use absolute ui-view names by prefixing with an exclamation

```
.state('second-page-content', {
     url: '/second-page-content',
     parent: 'mainCommonState',
     views: {
         '!content': {
             templateUrl: 'app/components/second-page-content.html'
             controller: 'secondPageCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'vm'
         }
     }
 })
```

### Read more about view targeting in the UI-Router views guide:

https://ui-router.github.io/guide/views#view-name-only

Comment: Thanks for the answer, btw I am not getting what I want: if I define an empty view named ```content``` in the ```mainCommonState```, and then define it inside the child states (using content@mainCommonState), it is not working... Can you please see the plunker that I have created? http://plnkr.co/edit/oTQzGVpvsjKiM22NGo5v?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GCKGErz68iuEir6Vo7sl?p=preview . you need to target the `ui-view` tag.  the `<div ui-view="content"></div>` tag was created in the *root* template, not in any state.  Target it using `content@` or `!content` as shown in the examples

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, in the end I preferred to use the absolute path (```!content```) because it makes more sense to me. Now the second level nested view is not automatically set as default even if the url is defined in the first tab instead of the first page (like suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001589/directing-the-user-to-a-child-state-when-they-are-transitioning-to-its-parent-st?rq=1). The updated plunker is here http://plnkr.co/edit/oTQzGVpvsjKiM22NGo5v?p=preview , have you got an idea on how to solve this?